# Armadillo load wav file to mat

Tags: c++, matlab, armadillo, libsndfile

I want to read wav file into mat using [Armadillo](http://arma.sourceforge.net/). It looks like [wavread](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/wavread.html) function in matlab:

```
[sample_data,sample_rate] = wavread('test.wav');
sample_data = sample_data(1 : sample_rate * 1.5);
```

Seems Armadillo doesn't support this, so I tried to use [libsndfile](http://www.mega-nerd.com/libsndfile/) lib:

```
SNDFILE     *infile = NULL ;
SF_INFO     sfinfo ;
infile = sf_open(filename, SFM_READ, &sfinfo);

int N = 1024;
double samples[N];
double sample_rate = sfinfo.samplerate;
sf_read_double(infile, samples, N);
```

My questions:

1. Is this way correct? Seem I can only read fixed amount samples.
2. How can I convert sample data to `mat` or `vec`?
3. Is there any way to access matrix by colon range index like this matlab code: `sample_data = sample_data(1 : sample_rate * 1.5);` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Yes, this way correct. If you need get all samples you can  do so:

   ```
   auto sample_chanels = sfinfo.channels;

   std::vector<std::vector<double>> vec;

   std::vector<double> temp(sample_chanels);

   while(sf_read_double(infile, temp.data(), sample_chanels))
   vec.push_back(temp);
   ```
2. For example so:

   ```
   mat m1(vec.size(),sample_chanels);

   for( size_t i=0;i<vec.size();i++)
      m1.row(i) = mat(vec[i]).t();
   ```
3. Complete analogy was not available, but you can use std::copy (), because the mat have member functions begin()

   ```
     arma::vec D(shift);

     if(shift < m1.size())
       std::copy(m1.begin(),m1.begin()+shift,D.begin());
   ```

Link to the complete example: 
http://pastebin.com/X4fgzBrR

Comment: do you mind if I ask you to help me on another question about `conv2` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31647574/armadillo-port-conv2-from-matlab ?  I need to port this function before build my code.