# Armadillo port conv2 from matlab

Tags: c++, matlab, armadillo

I'm going port [conv2](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/conv2.html) function in matlab with [Armadillo](http://arma.sourceforge.net/)

```
  C = conv2(A, B, 'same');
```

The problem is that I don't have any idea to start. I tried to see the matlab source code but it isn't available:

```
 >> type conv2
 'conv2' is a built-in function.
```

Does anyone know the alternative method in `Armadillo` or something to start with? As I only need conv2 with the `same` parameter.

Comment: Did you try to look at a text-book definition of convolution? Or even Wikipedia etc. It is quite straight forward to implement it (although not the most efficient computationally).

Comment: You just need to know about, `addition`, `multiplication` and `loops` to compute a convolution. Here's an applied example of [2D convolution](http://www.songho.ca/dsp/convolution/convolution2d_example.html). There is even source code if you read enough, but if you don't know enough about convolution, I strongly suggest you start by implementing a **1D** convolution first. Once you manage that, the 2D will be easy to understand.

Comment: I've also found a suitable duplicate for you that talks about the computational steps you need to get convolution to work.  However, the link that Hoki gave you is a very nice link as well.  That's what I point to for anyone that wants to learn convolution in 2D.